# How to pass an ArrayList from one Scene to another in JavaFX 2?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, javafx-2

So I've been trying for hours to solve this and it has been answered before in these forums but I would really appreciate some help since none really address my issue specifically or propose very differing solutions and I'm not quite sure what to try (even though I've tried all of them, I daresay).

The issue is this: I have a JavaFX application with 6 Scenes and their respective Controllers. I have a Person class that creates an object and that object I would like to store in an ArrayList that's global (that is, accessible by all the Scenes) so that when I close the application I can call another method to save it to a serialized file.

I don't actually use the ArrayList in the first couple of scenes because they're menus, so the actual method of creating the object is not run until the third Scene or so.

I have successfully created the Scenes and I can switch between them, I just have no idea

1. Where to declare the ArrayList (if in the main method, the main Class or where?)
2. How to pass this ArrayList between the Scenes so that they will all be able to access them.

I currently use this Class to switch between the Scenes:

```
public class SelectScene  {
    public void setScene(String fxmlFileName, String title, ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFileName));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(FinalDossier.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }
```

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this: basically all of them involve not using the static `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method, but creating an `FXMLLoader` instance instead.

One way would be to create the controllers in your code, initialize them with the shared List, and then pass them to `setController(...)`. In this version you would remove the `fx:controller` attributes from your FXML files.

It seems like a better way to do this in your case, though, would be to define a controller factory for the `FXMLLoader`. This is an object that tells the `FXMLLoader` how to get an instance from the class name defined in the `fx:controller` attribute. This just involves a little bit of reflection magic. So you would do something like

```
public class SelectScene  {


    private Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory ;

    public SelectScene(final List<...> data) {
        controllerFactory = new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Class<?> type) {
                try {
                    Constructor<?> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor(List.class);
                    return constructor.newInstance(data);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
                    return type.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // trouble...
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return null ;
                }
            }
         };
    }

    public void setScene(String fxmlFileName, String title, ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFileName));
        loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(FinalDossier.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

For the controllers that need access to the shared data, just define a constructor with a parameter taking a List:

```
public class MyController {
    private final List<...> data ;
    public MyController(List<...> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }
    public void initialize() {
        // usual initialize method
    }
}
```

For controllers without that constructor, the controller factory will fall back to the default constructor.

You can define the List wherever it's convenient: in the SelectScene class directly (as shown in the code), or you could define it earlier (in your start() method, for example), and pass it into the SelectScene constructor. It just depends where else you might need access to it.

UPDATE: Full example [here](https://github.com/james-d/Shared-Data-Controller/tree/master/src)

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve the problem. Except, now I can read the ArrayList from any class but I cannot write back to it (i.e. update it)... so that I can add stuff in one scene and different scenes will be able to see those changes...  how would I go about doing this?

Comment: As long as you pass the same instance of the list to each controller, this will work. So either make sure you only instantiate SelectScene once; or instantiate the List once (say in the start method) and pass the same instance of the list to a SelectScene constructor. If you need to observe the changes dynamically, you might need an ObservableList instead of a plain list.

Comment: To be able to use the method (setScene) from my SelectScene class I instantiate it in each controller... because I can't do it static, it throws an error... how (or where) would you instantiate it only once and yet be able to use it throughout all of the scenes?

Comment: In that case you can define the List as a parameter in the SelectScene constructor, and use that parameter to initialize the field. Then use the controllerFactory technique to pass a single list instance to all the controllers, and pass the list on to the SelectScene constructor. That way you have multiple SelectScenes but they all share the same list. I'll update the code a little... The critical thing is that you only create one List. If you create the List in your main app's start(...) method, and nowhere else, you can guarantee this.

Comment: Added an example at https://github.com/james-d/Shared-Data-Controller/tree/master/src

Comment: A little bit complex, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to see architecture of my [javafx-MultipleScreens-framework](https://github.com/zella/javafx-MultipleScreens-framework). In my sample you can store arraylist in MyScreenController class, because all screens have reference to it